# How to setup OpenCL on AMD videocard with opensource driver?

Tags: opencl, mesa

I have read this link - https://wiki.debian.org/ru/AtiHowTo
and decide to setup OpenCL.

> the r600g driver still have to load proprietary microcode into the GPU
>   to enable hardware acceleration. This firmware is usually included in
>   the kernel, but is packaged separately in Debian.

So, I installed firmware:

```
# apt-show-versions firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-linux
firmware-linux-nonfree:all/sid 0.40 uptodate
firmware-linux:all/sid 0.40 uptodate
```

Then I upgrade kernel version:

```
uname -v
#1 SMP PREEMPT RT Debian 3.12.8-1 (2014-01-19)
```

and checked kernel flags:

```
grep DRM_RADEON /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_DRM_RADEON=m
# CONFIG_DRM_RADEON_UMS is not set
grep AGP /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_AGP=y
CONFIG_AGP_AMD64=y
CONFIG_AGP_INTEL=y
CONFIG_AGP_SIS=y
CONFIG_AGP_VIA=y
```

Also I setup xserver version recent enough:

```
# apt-show-versions xorg
xorg:amd64/sid 1:7.7+5 uptodate
```

I choose radeon as driver:

> You most certainly are using wheezy's xserver-xorg-core which does not
>   provide xorg-video-abi-6.0 any more, and radeonhd is not available for
>   the newer xorg-video-abi because it has been removed from Debian

```
# apt-show-versions xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64/sid 1:7.3.0-1 uptodate
```

This gives me OpenGL working:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.0-devel (git-81144c0 saucy-oibaf-ppa+curaga)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0-devel (git-81144c0 saucy-oibaf-ppa+curaga)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

I am trying to use application which works with OpenCL.

This programs works ok on CPU:

```
$ mono scallion/bin/Debug/scallion.exe parallax
Cooking up some delicions scallions...
Putting 1 patterns into 1 buckets.
Using kernel optimized from file kernel.cl (Optimized4)
Using work group size 1
Compiling kernel... done.
LoopIteration:10  HashCount:167.77MH  Speed:7.8MH/s  Runtime:00:00:21
Predicted:19:38:20
Stopping and shutting down...

LoopIteration:11  HashCount:184.55MH  Speed:7.8MH/s  Runtime:00:00:23
Predicted:19:36:58  init: 2687ms / 1 (2687ms, 0.37/s)
generate key: 153ms / 6 (25.5ms, 39.22/s)
cpu precompute: 7ms / 6 (1.17ms, 857.14/s)
total without init: 23706ms / 1 (23706ms, 0.04/s)
set buffers: 0ms / 11 (0ms, 0/s)
write buffers: 0ms / 11 (0ms, 0/s)
read results: 23699ms / 11 (2154.45ms, 0.46/s)
check results: 0ms / 11 (0ms, 0/s)

7.78 million hashes per second

Stopping and shutting down...
```

But I am unable to detect GPU:

```
$ mono scallion/bin/Debug/scallion.exe
Usage: scallion [OPTIONS]+ regex [regex]+
Options:
      -l, --listdevices          Lists the devices that can be used.
      -d, --device=VALUE         Specifies the opencl device that should be used.
```

There is no GPU in the list of devices:

```
$ mono scallion/bin/Debug/scallion.exe -l
Id:0 Name:Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9650  @ 3.00GHz
    PreferredGroupSizeMultiple:1 ComputeUnits:4 ClockFrequency:2000
    MaxConstantBufferSize:65536 MaxConstantArgs:8 MaxMemAllocSize:2147483648
```

I am unable to find instructions on how to setup OpenCL:

```
apt-get install libclc-r600

apt-show-versions libclc-r600 ocl-icd-libopencl1
libclc-r600:all/saucy 0~git20140101-1~gd~s uptodate
ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64/sid 2.1.3-2 uptodate
```

and after starting application I receive an error:

```
~/github.com/lachesis/scallion$ mono ./scallion/bin/Debug/scallion.exe -l

Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: ErrorCode:'-1001'
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.CheckError (Int32 err) [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetPlatformIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetDeviceIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLRuntime.GetDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.ListDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException:
ErrorCode:'-1001'
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.CheckError (Int32 err) [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetPlatformIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLDeviceInfo.GetDeviceIds () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.CLRuntime.GetDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.ListDevices () [0x00000] in :0
at scallion.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
```

> The error code values are defined in opencl.h
>   It look like your platform is not configured properly.
>   CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR (-1001) error from clGetPlatformIDs.
>   That's because you do have the dispatcher, but no actual OpenCL drivers."

After

```
sudo apt-get install libopencl1-mesa

$ find / -iname «libMesaOpenCL.so*» 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1
```

In configuration file there should be

```
cat /etc/OpenCL/vendors/mesa.icd
libMesaOpenCL.so
```

The error is

```
fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/lib/clc/rv770-r600--.bc': No such file or directory
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

I eventually enabled the free OpenCL stack, and ran into very similar problems. I'll provide an abridged overview, of some of the relevant packages.

That `libopencl1-mesa` is just the ICD runtime, which is loaded into the generic `ocl-icd-libopencl1`.  Then `libclc` is used by `libopencl1-mesa` to deal with the OpenCL Kernels. Using an LLVM chipset specific backend, `libclc` generates instructions. You're missing the GPU chipset specific *glue*, which is provided by the missing `.bc`. This is greatly simplified, but for this problem it should suffice, still a good diagram would help immensely.

In your particular example, the `.bc`'s would be provided by `libclc-r600` However I'm not seeing anything for your chipset 'DONE', on this Freedesktop.org [GalliumCompute](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/GalliumCompute/) page. It appears the lowest supported chipset is the Evergreen (HD5000 Series).

<sub>* please recheck [GalliumCompute](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/GalliumCompute/) if you read this after 02-04-2014.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if 'nonfree' drivers are opensource.

Then, if you look at:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770
```

Looks like Gallium LLVM is used to render (not native GPU), so no guarantee, that OpenGL is accelerated by GPU. Anyway, if you use nonfree drivers, my advice is to download most recent drivers from AMD site & use them instead of currently installed.

Also, recent AMD APP SDK (from 2.8 on, if memory serves me right) is shipped apart from GPU driver, so you may try to use it instead of open package. It works at least on Ubuntu 12.04 (AMD drivers from repository + AMD APP SDK from AMD's site)

Comment: You're confusing the LLVMpipe software renderer with Gallium, it's just one of many possible Gallium renderers, in this case his is using the GPU. This is indicated by the `Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770`, on mine it says `Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD`.  When LLVMpipe software rendering is used, it instead reads `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe`

Comment: In addition he's indeed using the Free Drivers, of which R600 is the specific driver that covers his card's family. The nonfree indicated on that packagename is only for a required firmware blob.... I would say however the entire process is unnecessarily brutal, due to the extremely slow pace of distribution's mesa updates. Not to mention the always terrible state of mesa/distro graphical documentation.